# how do you remove () and commas from a list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x

Recently I developed a program that takes a list of numbers and finds the biggest number out of them that is divisible by 3.
It work however I don't understand how you change it to a normal list. Here is an example: I have

```
[(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
```

I would like to have

```
[334,343,334]
```

Thanks for the help

Following on from the great help I am receiving an unusual error to do with tuples Once again thanks for the help here it is;

```
import intercools 
list1 = []
stuff = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(stuff+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(stuff, L):
         list1.append(subset) 
print(list1) 
sep = [map(str,l)for l in list1]
nl = [int(''.join(s)) for s in sep]
print(nl)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And yet another:

```
ml = [(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)] 

sep = [map(str,l) for l in ml]

nl = [int(''.join(s)) for s in sep]

print(nl) # [334, 343, 334]
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
>>> LoT=[(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
```

You can use a string to join the tuple elements together then recast to an int:

```
>>> [int(''.join(map(str, t))) for t in LoT]
[334, 343, 334]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `literal_eval` from `ast` module like this way:

```
from ast import literal_eval 

a = [(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
b = [literal_eval("".join(str(j) for j in k)) for k in a]
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[334, 343, 334]
```

Also you can do it like this way:

```
a = [(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
b = [int("".join(str(j) for j in k)) for k in a]
```

Also, you can use `map` method to do it:

```
a = [(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
# Or using literal_eval
b = [int("".join(map(str, k))) for k in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions in `Python` are your friend.

```
t = [(3, 3, 4), (3, 4, 3), (3, 3, 4)]
str_tuple = [(str(x), str(y), str(y)) for (x, y, z) in t]
final = [int(''.join(x)) for x in str_tuple]
# [334, 343, 334]
```